# Adding 150,000 records to a listview without freezing UI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a listview loop that is adding 150,000 items to my listview. For testing purposes I moved this code to a background worker with delegates, but it still freezes up the UI. I am trying to find a solution so that it can add these items in the background while I do other stuff in the app. What solutions do you guys recommend?

this is what I am using

```
   Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListView1.Clear()

        ListView1.BeginUpdate()

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If bw.IsBusy Then bw.CancelAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
        For x = 1 To 125000
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem("Item " & x)
            If bw.CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            Else
                bw.ReportProgress(0, lvi)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged
        Try
            Dim lvi As ListViewItem = DirectCast(e.UserState, ListViewItem)
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
        ListView1.EndUpdate()
        If Not e.Cancelled Then
            Debug.Print("Done")
        Else
            Debug.Print("Cancelled")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: 150k is a lot to put in the UI, even for a non web app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try, it's a great example for what you would need... I also had a progress bar that shows the progress and such, see example image that is attached. Also I wasn't seeing any delegate that you need to perform such operation, mine has one that will be required. The reason is you are adding items to a control on the UI thread, in order to add items we need to know if an `Invoke` is required, if so we invoke otherwise we add the item to the control... Also I made the thread sleep, so it can take a break; this also ***prevents the UI from wanting to lock up here and there***, now it's responsive with ***NO FREEZING***.

```
 Option Strict On
 Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

Delegate Sub SetListItem(ByVal lstItem As ListViewItem) 'Your delegate..

'Start the process...
Private Sub btnStartProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartProcess.Click
    lvItems.Clear()
    bwList.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub AddListItem(ByVal lstItem As ListViewItem)
    If Me.lvItems.InvokeRequired Then 'Invoke if required...
        Dim d As New SetListItem(AddressOf AddListItem) 'Your delegate...
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {lstItem})
    Else 'Otherwise, no invoke required...
        Me.lvItems.Items.Add(lstItem)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub bwList_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwList.DoWork
    Dim intCount As Integer = CInt(txtCount.Text)
    Dim dblPercent As Integer = 100
    Dim intComplete As Integer = 0
    Dim li As ListViewItem = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 1 To CInt(txtCount.Text)
        If Not (bwList.CancellationPending) Then
            li = New ListViewItem
            li.Text = "Item " & i.ToString
            AddListItem(li)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) 'Give the thread a very..very short break...
        ElseIf (bwList.CancellationPending) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If

        intComplete = CInt(CSng(i) / CSng(intCount) * 100)
        If intComplete < dblPercent Then
            bwList.ReportProgress(intComplete)
        End If

        If li IsNot Nothing Then
            li = Nothing
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub bwList_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bwList.ProgressChanged
    pbList.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub bwList_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwList.RunWorkerCompleted
    If pbList.Value < 100 Then pbList.Value = 100
    MessageBox.Show(lvItems.Items.Count.ToString & " items were added!")
End Sub

Private Sub btnStopWork_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopWork.Click
    bwList.CancelAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRestart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRestart.Click
    pbList.Value = 0
    lvItems.Items.Clear()
    txtCount.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
End Class
```

Screenshot in action...

[image]

Comment: Could there be memory issues?

Comment: I ran with Ants profiler and didn't see anything of such. Why would there be?

Comment: @SysDragon great point. It could be possible, as that is quite a few items for a ListView. Im not sure about the OP's computer, but mine has plenty which wasn't affected. I even split out the items into chunks and it still didn't have a bad effect and was just as fast as if I didn't split it up.

Comment: Nice solution, this is great for dealing with large lists of data