# Filling DataGridView with ImageColumn in BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, backgroundworker

I want to fill *dgv1* in *BackgroundWorker*

I've tried to do something similar to [this solution by MrCoDeXeR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421503/adding-150-000-records-to-a-listview-without-freezing-ui/24422586#24422586) :

```
Delegate Sub SetRow(ByVal row As DataGridViewRow)

Private Sub AddRow(ByVal row As DataGridViewRow)
    If Me.dgv1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetRow(AddressOf AddRow)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {row})
    Else
        Me.dgv1.Rows.Add(row)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub bgw1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw1.DoWork

   '...        

    Dim imgcol1 As New DataGridViewImageColumn
    Dim tmpDGV As New DataGridView
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Nothing

    With tmpDGV
        .Columns.Insert(0, imgcol1)
        .Columns.Add("name", "")
        .Columns.Add("path", "")
    End With

    For Each fi In f1_tab

        If (bgw1.CancellationPending = True) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If

    '...
        If found Then

              row = New DataGridViewRow
              tmpDGV.Rows.Add(exeIcon, fi.Name, fi.FullName)
              row = tmpDGV.Rows(tmpDGV.Rows.Count - 1)
              AddRow(row)

              Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)

        End If

        If row IsNot Nothing Then
               row = Nothing
        End If

        bgw1.ReportProgress(src_progress)

    Next
End Sub
```

However I get exception at *Me.dgv1.Rows.Add(row)* :

> Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control.

How to fix this? Or maybe I should do this in a different way?

Comment: The `DoWork` event handler of the `BackgroundWorker` is executed on a secondary thread.  You don't do anything that modifies a control on a secondary thread.  You're calling `Rows.Add` on your grid.  No.

Comment: My solution was for adding items such as listviewitems, you shouldn't approach filling your grid this way. Just set the datasource for the grid. The reason why in my other solution is because I was dealing with a timely operation that was locking up the UI from adding so many items. Also as @Shell has mentioned your adding that row twice...

Answer (score 0):

You are adding row twice.

```
tmpDGV.Rows.Add(exeIcon, fi.Name, fi.FullName)   'First time
row = tmpDGV.Rows(tmpDGV.Rows.Count - 1)
AddRow(row) 'Second time
```

try to set only values in `row` object instead of adding it again in `tmpdDGV`.

Comment: that also didn't help, I wasn't getting error but nothing was adding to dgv, I deleted dgv and switched to Listview, did few tweaks so it look like my dgv and used Mr CoDeXer method I mentioned in my question and now everything works as I expected, but thanks for help anyway guys :)